# How to fix this PHP warning in WP-Admin after upgrading to 3.1.2?

Tags: php, customization, upgrade, warnings

I just upgraded from 3.0 to 3.1.2 and in the comments column under Posts in the WP Admin, this error keeps appearing for every row:

> Warning: number_format() expects
>   parameter 1 to be double, string given
>   in
>   /path/mysite/wp-includes/functions.php
>   on line 155

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: What Plugins do you have installed?

Comment: Advanced Excerpt, Akismet, Category pagination fix, Disqus Comment System, Feed JSON, WordPress Importer, and Yet Another RElated Posts plugin

Comment: What normally displays in that column? That is not a default Column (EDIT: actually, yes it is). I suspect the warning is coming from Disqus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Comments" column is not a default/core column in the "Posts" page. Perhaps it is being generated by your Disqus Plugin?

Try temporarily disabling the Disqus Plugin, and see if the PHP notices go away.

EDIT: actually, it *is* a default column. But I still suspect Disqus is causing the PHP warning.

Comment: This error [has been reported here for the Disqus plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10346/wordpress-3-1-and-disqus-throws-warning-number-format-error-in-posts-list). So if Zoolander can confirm it is Disqus, this question becomes a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, when I deactivated the Disqus plug-in, the warning went away. Unfortunately, it needs to remain activated, so now it's just a matter of fixing the plug-in. :(